# How to specify Ruby regex when using Active Record in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

To get all jobs which `invoice_number` is a pure number I do:

```
Job.where("invoice_number REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$'")
```

Is it possible to do the same by specifying the regex in Ruby rather than MySQL ?

Comment: do you want to write it in ruby but them pass it to mysql, or do you want to to the regexp matching at the application layer?

Comment: I prefer the regex matching to be done at the database level, and I want to write the regex itself in Ruby.

Comment: So you're asking for a ruby-to-mysql regex translator?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, I was hoping there is something like that built in Rails.

Comment: @Misha: That would perhaps be a good addition to ActiveRecord, but sadly it doesn't exist. Best thing is to cleanly tuck it away in a named scope, as per the second half of my answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way is

```
Job.all.select{|j| j =~ /^\d+$/}
```

but it will not be as efficient as the MySQL version.

Another possibility is to use a named scope to hide the ugly SQL:

```
  named_scope :all_digits, lambda { |regex_str|
    { :condition => [" invoice_number REGEXP '?' " , regex_str] }
  }
```

Then you have `Job.all_digits`.

Note that in the second example, you are assembling a query for the database, so `regex_str` needs to be a MySQL regex string instead of a Ruby Regex object, which has a slightly different syntax.

Comment: Did you test the second version? I tried `Job.where(["invoice_number REGEXP '?'", /\d+/])` and it returned an error.

Comment: The named scope still uses the database, so you need to pass in a MySQL regex string rather than a ruby regex object.

Comment: Yeah I got caught on that too. I think you should clarify that a MySQL regex != a Ruby regex for beginners (like me)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is either [Regexp#tos](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Regexp.html#method-i-to_s) or [Regexp#source](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Regexp.html#method-i-source) or [Regexp#inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Regexp.html#method-i-inspect).

But I can't think of why you would want to do this -- Ruby doesn't make it easy to compose `Regexp`s programmatically (which is the only reason I can think of why one might want to compose at one level and submit it to another).

Answer (score 1):

we can write like

```
scope :only_valid_email_record , :conditions=>["email_id ~ ?","^([a-zA-Z0-9_.'-])+@(([a-zA0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$"]
```

It works fine in rails 3.

Comment: Sorry, this fails on [http://louvre.museum/](http://louvre.museum/) and many others.