# ActiveRecord search on field with criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I'm relatively new to Rails and ActiveRecord. I'm storing phone numbers in ActiveRecord fields (phone_number) that can be in a number of formats "+1 928 929 3829" or "393 938 0293" or "392-937-9283" (you get the idea).

Later I'm capturing a 10 digit phone number (so it will always be like "3939380293") and then trying to match that to my ActiveRecord phone number field. The operation I want to do is match against the last 10 numeric characters of phone_number.

I've tried looking at the different SQL-type query constraints that you can use in queries, but I'm having trouble finding exactly what I need or making the logic leap.

Can anyone offer some advice here?

Answer (score 0):

I would do followings

1 - having a VARCHAR field for phone number, which will save numbers in any format (Ex: "+1 928 929 3829" or "393 938 0293" or "392-937-9283")

2 - Have a Activerecord to select the phone number with a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059770/how-to-specify-ruby-regex-when-using-active-record-in-rails).

My most favourite regex writers are [rubular](http://rubular.com/), [regexper](http://www.regexper.com/)

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I might be able to do that? I'm familiar with regexes, but how can I use a regex for querying database tables. Can you point me to some sample code?