# Rails query join on regex

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, join

This is a query run very infrequently (as admin), and it's not worth indexing/ using up RAM with sphinx.

So, with the variables set up something like this:
fn, ln, em = 'John', 'Smith', 'johnsmith@gmail.com'

The query is something like this:

```
profiles = Profile.joins(:user).where(:users=>{"email" => em}).
  where("first_name LIKE '%#{fn}%' AND last_name LIKE '%#{ln}%'")
```

Except that I want the email to accept a substring (e.g. if em == 'th@gm', then it should match 'johnsmith@gmail.com'). How do you write this to do a join selecting only those users with a variable matching a regex?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(I got my inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059770/how-to-specify-ruby-regex-when-using-active-record-in-rails)):

Have you tried something like:

```
profiles = Profile.joins(:user).where("first_name LIKE ? AND last_name LIKE ?", "%#{fn}%", "%#{ln}%")
profiles.select{|p| p.user.email =~ /#{em}/}
```

Comment: This is likely less efficient than a pure-SQL solution. Whether that's worth worrying about or not depends on how many Profiles there are likely to be that match the `where` clause but would fail the email test. If it's only a handful, this is probably a good solution. If there are many, it's less so.

Comment: Well, if we were aiming at efficiency, it would be better to use a stored procedure.  However, since ActiveRecord's top priority isn't efficiency (and this is a Rails-esque question), I figured this is a workable answer.

Comment: Yes - this is a great solution. It's an essential query, but it is rarely required and not performance critical. There are many users, but it can be handled in memory at present - so a ruby select seems appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: @muistooshort: You're right.  I was just copying the OP's code.  I'll fix that.

Comment: mu, did a search and ended up looking at a previous answer of yours. Would you consider this safe from SQL injection? profiles = Profile.where("first_name LIKE '%#{fn.gsub(/[!%_]/) { |x| '!' + x }}%' ESCAPE '!' AND last_name LIKE '%#{ln.gsub(/[!%_]/) { |x| '!' + x }}%' ESCAPE '!'")